# I Want to use Uber Ride Requests via Deep Linking in my website which is in c# so if user want he can book his Ride

Tags: angularjs, c#-4.0, model-view-controller, uber-api

I Want to use [UBER Ride Requests via Deep Linking](https://developer.uber.com/docs/deep-linking#section-platform-examples) in my website which is in c# so if user can book his Ride. how can i check whether a mobile on which my site  open have UBER app installed,My site is in angular and in c#,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the universal link, as described in the documentation:

> Both the Android and iOS Uber apps support universal deep links. When linking from a mobile website, use **https://m.uber.com/ul** instead of uber://. The operating system will automatically open the Uber app if it is installed or fall back to our mobile site, which will open the phone's app store when applicable.